# How to remove extra space between the last visible word and ellipsis dots?

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I am using CSS to trim a sentence using the ellipsis method.

For the sentence

```
This is a test sentence grammatically correct.
```

The result I am getting is this:

```
This is a test sentence ...
```

The above result is because the ellipsis dots starts from the word "grammatically" before which there is a space. What I want to do is no matter if the ellipsis start for a new word after a space or not there shouldn't be any space between the last visible word (here, "sentence") and the ellipsis.

I want this:

```
This is a test sentence...
```

Is it possible?

```css
p {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
<p>This is a test sentence grammatically correct.</p>
```

**NOTE:** The sentence is dynamic and changes. Therefore, I can't used fixed width like `158px` instead of `160px` or something like that as every word is of different length. `158px` for example, might work for the above sentence but what if the last visible word is "the" instead of "sentence" ? In that case `158px` fixed width won't work as I would need to go much lower. Therefore, a dynamic solution is required here which curbs the space no matter what the sentence or the last visible word is.

Comment: Do you expect the ellipsis to always start from a word boundary?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to reproduce the spacing issue in the following snippet ?

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<p>
This is a test sentence </p>
```

Comment: I realized something important after your answer and I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: got it, so the space is coming from your text input itself

Comment: I guess so.. and I was hoping to curb this space out with CSS.

Comment: Would the text be a dynamic one? Or just a static text? Because, with css, we cannot check the spaces and eliminate if any.

Comment: Dynamic.. It would change every now and then. It's a text message.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible as of my knowledge.. please do let me know too if you find a solution

Comment: @AbinThaha  My answer is at the bottom.  Curious how it works out for you guys.

Comment: Yes..it's a way to implement the same functionality. But was checking the same using ellipsis only.. let the one raised the question decides if this would work for him, or he needs a solution using ellipsis only

Answer (score 0):

I revised my answer.

I have changed the width to 25%, which you can adjust to your own needs. You may also adjust this to @media responsiveness.

The first `<span>` is the area you will display.

The point to be careful of, if you do not want words to be cut, keep your characters limited to a certain number of characters.  You should leave enough space in the end for the ellipses, so calculate your character length accordingly.

Hope it works for you.

```css
.dynamic {
  width: 25%;
  height: 1.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamic > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre;
}
.dynamic > span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "…";
}
.dynamic > span:last-child::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamic">
<span>This is a test sentence</span> <span>gramatically correct.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this can be a dynamic solution as every word is of different length. What if instead of "sentence" the last word was "is" ? In that case `158px` can't be a precise solution.

Comment: @RelaxingMusic I revised my answer yesterday.  Have you checked?

Comment: How do you expect me to divide a dynamic sentence in two parts like this? That's not possible!

Comment: Aren't you writing your own sentences?  Add the code as text format like an html and give it your class.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at my question again. Please have a look at the "NOTE" section.

Comment: If you are referring to, let's say, people who comment and you have no control over their commenting, then yes, this would not work unless their is a script behind.  Yet, if you are going to write a paragraph, then you can define where your sentence should get cut off.

Comment: If it would have been a static text I would have had already easily handled it myself and wouldn't have had raised a question here for such a simple task. The problem lies in the dynamic nature of the sentence. It would be chat messages where the last message (the most recent one) would be shown in the conversation list as happens in Whataspp. So yes, no control over it. I guess I will have to let this issue slide for now.

Comment: I guess it's a way to find out that it's not possible unless there is a script.  Perhaps that is what you can ask that you get help with a script be it php or javascript.  Depends on your platform you are using.